# Generate Keyword in VHDL

Tags: compiler-errors, vhdl, hdl, alu

I am trying to create a carry-look-ahead adder/subtractor unit as part of an ALU using VHDL.
unlike a conventional adder, this unit must recognize both 32-bit unpacked data and 16-bit packed data and treat them accordingly. So, if I choose to add two 32-bit unpacked quantities, it should give me a 32-bit unpacked result. However, if I want to add four 16-bit packed quantities, it should give me two 16-bit packed results.

ie. 
32_bit_A + 32_bit_B = 32_bit_A+B 
16_bit_A + 16_bit_B, 16_bit_C + 16_bit_D = 16_bit_A+B, 16_bit_C+D

I've tried to implement such a thing using a MODE bit which will determine whether or not I'm using packed or unpacked data, however, my VHDL compiler keeps telling me that it it is expecting the `generate` keyword, among other errors that I am rather confused about. **I should note that this design compiles and works perfectly for unpacked data, that is, without the conditional statements and cla4 and cla5.** I would appreciate some explanation as to what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity thirty_two_bit_cla is
    port
    (
    A : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);  -- 32-bit augend
    B : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);  -- 32-bit addend
    SUM : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);  -- 32-bit sum
    CARRY_OUT : out std_logic;                -- carry out
    CARRY_IN  : in  std_logic;                -- carry in
    P_G       : out std_logic;                -- group propagate
    G_G       : out std_logic;                -- group generate
    MODE      : in  std_logic                 -- 16 or 32-bit addition (0 or 1 respectively)
    );
end thirty_two_bit_cla;

architecture structural of thirty_two_bit_cla is

signal G : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);      --generate signals         
signal P : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);      --propagate signals
signal C : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);      --carry signals

begin
    --Treat data as 32-bit unpacked
    if(MODE = '1') then
    sixteen_bit_cla0: entity sixteen_bit_cla port map(A=>A(15 downto 0),
                                                      B=>B(15 downto 0),
                                                  SUM=>SUM(15 downto 0),
                                                         CARRY_IN=>C(0),
                                                            P_G => P(0),
                                                           G_G => G(0));

    sixteen_bit_cla1: entity sixteen_bit_cla port map(A=>A(31 downto 16),
                                                      B=>B(31 downto 16),
                                                  SUM=>SUM(31 downto 16),
                                                          CARRY_IN=>C(1),
                                                             P_G => P(1),
                                                            G_G => G(1));


    C(0) <= CARRY_IN;
    C(1) <= G(0) or (P(0) and C(0));
    C(2) <= G(1) or (P(1) and C(1));


    CARRY_OUT <= C(2);
    G_G<=C(2);
    P_G <= P(0) and P(1);

    --Treat data as 16-bit packed
    elsif (MODE = '0') then
    sixteen_bit_cla4: entity sixteen_bit_cla port map(A=>A(15 downto 0),
                                                      B=>B(15 downto 0),
                                                  SUM=>SUM(15 downto 0),
                                                    CARRY_IN=>CARRY_IN);

    sixteen_bit_cla5: entity sixteen_bit_cla port map(A=>A(31 downto 16),
                                                      B=>B(31 downto 16),
                                                  SUM=>SUM(31 downto 16),
                                                     CARRY_IN=>CARRY_IN);
    end if;

end structural;
```

Errors:

```
# Compile Entity "thirty_two_bit_cla"
# Compile Architecture "structural" of Entity "thirty_two_bit_cla"
# Error: COMP96_0329: 32 bit cla.vhd : (26, 5): Generate statement must have a label.
# Error: COMP96_0019: 32 bit cla.vhd : (26, 20): Keyword 'generate' expected.
# Error: COMP96_0019: 32 bit cla.vhd : (52, 2): Keyword 'end' expected.
# Error: COMP96_0016: 32 bit cla.vhd : (52, 8): Design unit declaration expected.
# Compile Entity "sixteen_bit_cla"
# Error: COMP96_0019: 32 bit cla.vhd : (53, 43): Keyword 'is' expected.
# Error: COMP96_0015: 32 bit cla.vhd : (53, 48): '(' expected.
# Error: COMP96_0028: 32 bit cla.vhd : (53, 48): Identifier or keyword expected.
# Error: COMP96_0015: 32 bit cla.vhd : (53, 48): ';' expected.
# Error: COMP96_0019: 32 bit cla.vhd : (53, 51): Keyword 'end' expected.
# Error: COMP96_0015: 32 bit cla.vhd : (53, 51): ';' expected.
# Error: COMP96_0016: 32 bit cla.vhd : (53, 52): Design unit declaration expected.
# Compile Entity "sixteen_bit_cla"
# Error: COMP96_0019: 32 bit cla.vhd : (58, 45): Keyword 'is' expected.
# Error: COMP96_0015: 32 bit cla.vhd : (58, 50): '(' expected.
# Error: COMP96_0028: 32 bit cla.vhd : (58, 50): Identifier or keyword expected.
# Error: COMP96_0015: 32 bit cla.vhd : (58, 50): ';' expected.
# Error: COMP96_0019: 32 bit cla.vhd : (58, 53): Keyword 'end' expected.
# Error: COMP96_0015: 32 bit cla.vhd : (58, 53): ';' expected.
# Error: COMP96_0016: 32 bit cla.vhd : (58, 54): Design unit declaration expected.
# Compile failure 18 Errors 0 Warnings  Analysis time :  16.0 [ms]
# ULM: Warning: ULM_0021 Architecture `structural' of entity `register_file.thirty_two_bit_cla' is not up-to-date.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use a sequential IF statement outside of a process.  It expects the keyword IF to be part of a generate scheme and generate statement.

(And no, you don't want to be using a generate statement).  You want to steer data, not instantiations.  If your 16 bit adder connections are correct it looks like you're only manipulating the carry chain.  You don't need to duplicate the adders to do that.

This should give you the equivalent of your MODE selected operation, save there are no NULL assignments to CARRY_OUT, G_G and P_G:

```
begin
--Treat data as 32-bit unpacked
-- if(MODE = '1') then
sixteen_bit_cla0: entity sixteen_bit_cla port map(A=>A(15 downto 0),
                                                  B=>B(15 downto 0),
                                              SUM=>SUM(15 downto 0),
                                                     CARRY_IN=>C(0),
                                                        P_G => P(0),
                                                       G_G => G(0));

sixteen_bit_cla1: entity sixteen_bit_cla port map(A=>A(31 downto 16),
                                                  B=>B(31 downto 16),
                                              SUM=>SUM(31 downto 16),
                                                      CARRY_IN=>C(1),
                                                         P_G => P(1),
                                                        G_G => G(1));


C(0) <= CARRY_IN;  -- both modes
C(1) <= G(0) or (P(0) and C(0)) when MODE = '1' else
        CARRY_IN;
C(2) <= G(1) or (P(1) and C(1));


CARRY_OUT <= C(2) when MODE = '1' else
             '0';
G_G<=C(2)  when MODE = '1' else
      '0';
P_G <= P(0) and P(1) when MODE = '1' else
       '0';
-- 
-- --Treat data as 16-bit packed
-- elsif (MODE = '0') then
-- sixteen_bit_cla4: entity sixteen_bit_cla port map(A=>A(15 downto 0),
--                                                   B=>B(15 downto 0),
--                                               SUM=>SUM(15 downto 0),
--                                                 CARRY_IN=>CARRY_IN);
-- 
-- sixteen_bit_cla5: entity sixteen_bit_cla port map(A=>A(31 downto 16),
--                                                   B=>B(31 downto 16),
--                                               SUM=>SUM(31 downto 16),
--                                                  CARRY_IN=>CARRY_IN);
-- end if;

end structural;
```

I'm not going to stop and write sixteen_bit_cla and a testbench to verify it.  Caveat Emptor.

Comment: Thanks, seems to work like a charm! I'm so rusty with my VHDL that I forgot you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just write `a <= b + c;` instead of creating your own ripple carry adder?

This can be just as efficient (or even more efficient) compared to hand coding your adder. It will be instructing to try both and run them through your synthesis tool.

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately, the assignment mandated we make a carry-look-ahead adder in a structural fashion (I suppose for the educational aspect). However, I did do the multiplier like you had suggested, with a `*` instead.